# Change JQuery action at form submit based on checkbox

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Need to change the url a person goes to after submit based on checkbox in form.

Currently using:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    if ($('input[name=dance_inc_setup]').is(':checked')){
        $('form').attr('action', 'checkout2');   
    }
});
```

the form is at danceinc.org

I already have some scripts working but can't get this one to work.  Thanks.

Comment: How about actually doing it when the input changes, and not when the form submits.

Comment: If I did that, I would not capture the data entered in the form.  Right?

Comment: What, you're not capturing anything now, you're just changing an attribute, and you should be changing that attribute when the checkbox changes, not when the form submits. Just do this -> http://jsfiddle.net/HQ47C/

Comment: Before they get to the checkbox (and after) there is stuff to fill out I need to get.

Comment: Changing the attribute doesn't submit the form, I don't think you're really getting this ?

Comment: Oh, I get what you are saying now.  So I put the script in the header and it still goes to default url (set in the Wordpress plugin).  I've been at this for a couple days and I get the feeling the plugin is keeping it from happening. (and yes, I don't get this stuff at all)

Comment: The script need to be "wrapped" with jQuery(document).ready(function($) to load at proper time (don't even know what that means but it works)

Comment: Yes it does, Wordpress is in noConflict mode by default, and it's well documented in [**The Codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $("form").submit(function(){
     if ($("input[name='dance_inc_setup']").is(":checked")){
        $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'checkout2'); 
      }
    });
```

You forgot to add quotes around the input name. I changed all single quotes to double quotes to be consisitent.

Comment: No luck, still went to the default url

Comment: Makes no difference, the quotes are optional as there are no special characters in the name.

Comment: Try this `$('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'checkout2');` Check updated answer

Comment: can you put a console.log in submit function just to check if it's being executed ? Also, I think some other jquery might be running after this - which might be changing url to default, could that be the case ?

Comment: I think you may be right about the "running after" thing (i.e. something about the plugin that creates the form).  Don't know how do the console.log thing but can tell you the three functions right before this one are all running fine.

Comment: write `console.log("running inside submit")` inside the function submit. Check console in browser to see if this runs when you hit submit.

Answer (score 0):

For Jay's solution to work in WordPress with this plugin (Participant Database), the script has to load at the proper time like Ani alluded to:

```
     // the wrapper to load at appropriate time
     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     //Use name= from the input tag in source
     $('input[name=PUT FIELD NAME HERE]').on('change', function() {
     if (this.checked) {
     $('form').attr('action', 'PAGENAME');
}
});
});
```

Seems to work but, given some persistence built into the plugin, when testing, clear cache each time else second try will default to URL set in plugin settings.